# Плавающий текст в Label

Tags: c#, winforms

В случае если текст длиннее чем `Label`, как сделать так, чтобы этот текст плыл в левую сторону, потом появлялся снова и после небольшой паузы снова начинал плыть? Как в новостной строке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Бегущая строка на Windows Forms создается через Panel,Timer и Label. Создайте эти 3 контрола (нужный вам текст напишите в Label) саму Label поместите в Panel как на рисунке (за пределы панели label не выйдет) 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код :

```
   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (label1.Left > -label1.Width)
        {
            label1.Left -= 5;
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Left = panel1.Width;
        }
    }
```

для выбора в Label текста из ListBox :

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if (label1.Text.Length > 10) // сравнение между количеством символов и некоторым значением, которое отражает ширину panel1
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            label1.Location = new Point(0,0); // label должен находится внутри panel
        }
    }
```

Не забудьте

```
    label1.AutoSize = true
```

Comment: А что если текст в Label это выделенная строчка в LIstBox?

Comment: Есть проблема. Строка плывет, но отображается только та часть которая влазит в Label. Плавающая строка и нужна для того чтобы отобразить весь текст, а получается отображается как и раньше, только кусок который влазит в Label, но теперь он плывет.

Comment: у вас текст Labl'a не влазит полностью в label ?

Comment: @River свойство Label1 - AutoSize поставлено в true ?

Comment: Текст Label не всегда влазит. В Label отображается выделенная строка в ListBox, а строки там есть короткие и очень длинные.

Comment: @River У Label1 свойство AutoSize false или true ?

Comment: AutoSize = True

Comment: @River покажите код как заполняете Label.

Comment: Извиняюсь, все работает, не поправил ошибку в коде. Еще один вопрос. Текст плывет всегда. Как сделать чтобы он был на месте если он помещается на Panel, а когда он слишком большой тогда и поплывет?

Comment: @River поправил.

Comment: Все равно плывет.

Comment: @River удалите             `timer1.Start();` из Form_Load. Оставьте только в условии в событии `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: Не двигается стандартный Text у Label, но если выбрать строку в ListBox которая точно влазит она все равно плывет. Извините.

Comment: @River Я вас не понимаю. Вот мое решение и там все работает : http://dropmefiles.com/Ogo5n

Comment: А у меня все едет. Может дело в том что вы добавляете в ListBox через  listBox1.Items.Add(" "), а у меня через openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() и openFileDialog1_FileOk

Comment: @River Покажите свой проект.

Comment: @River вот тут `if (label_name.Text.Length > 10)`  вместо 10 поставь 100 хотя бы

Comment: Что-то я совсем уже. Нужно будет только привязать к Panel на которой расположен Label. А то как я понимаю текст отображается только в пределах панели где Label, но едет по всей ширине формы, потому когда он уехал его еще ждать нужно. Спасибо большое за помощь, из извините глупость.

Comment: @River пожалуйста=). ничего страшного -научитесь. я уверен что и этот способ далеко не самый лучший. Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, можете плюсануть коммент )